# React share contents on social media

Tags: reactjs, react-share

Dear stack over flow community. 
I am building a react app using create react app where I will show a random joke fetched from an external API.

Here is the code for react component

```
   import React from "react"
   function Home(props) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{props.joke.setup}</h2>
                    <h3>{props.joke.punchline}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I want to include a share functionality to share the current joke on social media. I tried react-share package, but the share button used in there only allows to pass a url. Which in my case will be the base url of my app, and could not include the current joke that I am displaying.

```
    import { FacebookShareButton, FacebookIcon } from "react-share"
    <FacebookShareButton url="#">
        <FacebookIcon logoFillColor="white" />
    </FacebookShareButton>
```

How could I include a share button that shares the content of react components, values of state or props rather than just url?
For example a share button like the above but has additional props that I can pass content in, props.joke.setup, props.joke.punchline
Thank you very much

Comment: This is not the right way to ask questions on stackoverflow , You need to provide the code and show us what you have done so far to make it work.
You cannot just expect us to guess your problem and give a solution

Comment: I am very sorry, I was new in this and didn't get exactly the rule. I didn't include the code because I thought this question is less about the error in the code, and more about wether there is a way to do a certain thing in general. I didn't mean to waste people's time to ask unclear questions. So now I edit the post, and hope this is more acceptable to the community. Again apologize.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found a way myself. Sorry I should have read the documentation of react-share package better.
There is optional props that you can pass to the share button. So I did this.

```
<FacebookShareButton
    url="someurl"
    quote={props.joke.setup + props.joke.punchline}
    hashtag="#programing joke">
    <FacebookIcon logoFillColor="white" />
</FacebookShareButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Also Use Share Social just use below code

```
const style = {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    padding: '0 30px',
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
};

console.log(currentPlaylist._id);

return (
    <>
        <ShareSocial 
            style={style}
            url ={currentPlaylist._id}
            socialTypes={['facebook','twitter','reddit','linkedin','email','pinterest']}
        />
    </>
)
```